# 2^3 Factorial design in Yates' notation

Tags: self-study, experiment-design, confounding, blocking, fractional-factorial

Consider a $2^3$ factorial design lay out in 2 blocks, each of size 4, as follows
Block I  {1, a, b, c}
Block II {ab, ac, bc, abc}
Here, the treatments combinations are written in  Yates’ notation. Then which of the following are always true?
a)  Main effect  A is confounded
b)  Main effect  B is unconfounded
c)  Interaction AB,BC,AC are all unconfounded
d)  Interaction ABC  is confounded